# Save Keras ModelCheckpoints in Google Cloud Bucket

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, keras, hdf5, h5py

I'm working on training a LSTM network on Google Cloud Machine Learning Engine using Keras with TensorFlow backend. I managed it to deploy my model and perform a successful training task after some adjustments to the gcloud and my python script.

I then tried to make my model save checkpoints after every epoch using Keras [modelCheckpoint callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/#modelcheckpoint). Running a local training job with Google Cloud works perfectly as expected. The weights are getting stored in the specified path after each epoch. But when I try to run the same job online on Google Cloud Machine Learning Engine the `weights.hdf5` does not get written to my Google Cloud Bucket. Instead I get the following error:

```
...
File "h5f.pyx", line 71, in h5py.h5f.open (h5py/h5f.c:1797)
IOError: Unable to open file (Unable to open file: name = 
'gs://.../weights.hdf5', errno = 2, error message = 'no such file or
directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)
```

I investigated this issue and it turned out, that there is no Problem with the the Bucket itself, as Keras [Tensorboard callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/#tensorboard) does work fine and writes the expected output to the same bucket. I also made sure that `h5py` gets included by providing it in the `setup.py` located at:

```
├── setup.py
    └── trainer
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── ...
```

The actual include in `setup.py` is shown below:

```
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='kerasLSTM',
      version='0.1',
      packages=find_packages(),
      author='Kevin Katzke',
      install_requires=['keras','h5py','simplejson'],
      zip_safe=False)
```

I guess the problem comes down to the fact that GCS cannot be accessed with Pythons `open` for I/O since it instead provides a custom implementation:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io

with file_io.FileIO("gs://...", 'r') as f:
    f.write("Hi!")
```

After checking how Keras modelCheckpoint callback implements the actual file writing and it turned out, that it is using [h5py.File()](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/file.html?highlight=open) for I/O:

```
 with h5py.File(filepath, mode='w') as f:
    f.attrs['keras_version'] = str(keras_version).encode('utf8')
    f.attrs['backend'] = K.backend().encode('utf8')
    f.attrs['model_config'] = json.dumps({
        'class_name': model.__class__.__name__,
        'config': model.get_config()
 }, default=get_json_type).encode('utf8')
```

And as the `h5py package` is a Pythonic interface to the `HDF5 binary data format` the `h5py.File()` seems to call an underlying `HDF5` functionality written in Fortran as far as I can tell: [source](https://github.com/mokus0/hdf5/blob/master/fortran/examples/h5_rdwt.f90), [documentation](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5F.html#File-Open).

How can I fix this and make the modelCheckpoint callback write to my GCS Bucket? Is there a way for "monkey patching" to somehow overwrite how a hdf5 file is opened to make it use GCS's `file_io.FileIO()`?

Comment: This may not apply to CloudML but one thing you may want to explore is the GCSFUSE utility. I don't know if you can use it in the context of CloudML, but I normally use when running TF on regular Google Cloud VMs that run Ubuntu. Gcsfuse lets you map a local directory on the Ubuntu VM to a Google Cloud Bucket, so to Python the cloud bucket starts to look like a regular dir. Again, not sure if you can use it with CloudML but think about it..

Comment: Thanks @VS_FF I will investigate your suggestion and give you feedback on this.

Comment: Leaving this here for anyone who are still having the same problem. I was able to solve (well, a workaround) this problem by creating a custom callback to copy checkpoints into GCS bucket after every epoch. I have already answered this on another question in stackoverflow. Please find it here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/69226186/15319462

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue can be solved with the following piece of code:

```
# Save Keras ModelCheckpoints locally
model.save('model.h5')

# Copy model.h5 over to Google Cloud Storage
with file_io.FileIO('model.h5', mode='r') as input_f:
    with file_io.FileIO('model.h5', mode='w+') as output_f:
        output_f.write(input_f.read())
        print("Saved model.h5 to GCS")
```

The model.h5 is saved on local filesystem and the copied over to GCS. As [Jochen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8611941/jochen) pointed out, there currently is no easy support to write HDF5 model checkpoints to GCS. With this hack it is possible to write the data until an easier solution is provided.

Answer (score 17):

I might be a bit late on this, but for the sake of future visitors I would describe the whole process of how to adapt the code that was previously run locally to be GoogleML-aware from the IO point of view.

1. Python standard `open(file_name, mode)` does not work with buckets (`gs://...../file_name`). One needs to `from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io` and change all calls to `open(file_name, mode)` to `file_io.FileIO(file_name, mode=mode)` (note the named `mode` parameter). The interface of the opened handle is the same.
2. *Keras* and/or other libraries mostly use standard `open(file_name, mode)` internally. That said, something like `trained_model.save(file_path)` calls to 3rd-party libraries will fail to store the result to the bucket. The only way to retrieve a model after the job has finished successfully would be to *store it locally and then move to the bucket*.

The code below is quite inefficient, because it loads the whole model at once and then dumps it to the bucket, but it worked for me for relatively small models:

```
model.save(file_path)

with file_io.FileIO(file_path, mode='rb') as if:
    with file_io.FileIO(os.path.join(model_dir, file_path), mode='wb+') as of:
        of.write(if.read())
```

The mode *must* be set to binary for both reading and writing.

When the file is relatively big, it makes sense to read and write it in chunks to decrease memory consumption.

3. Before running a real task, I would advise to run a stub that simply saves a file to remote bucket.

This implementation, temporarily put instead of real `train_model` call, should do:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument(
        '--job-dir',
        help='GCS location with read/write access',
        required=True
    )

    args = parser.parse_args()
    arguments = args.__dict__
    job_dir = arguments.pop('job_dir')

    with file_io.FileIO(os.path.join(job_dir, "test.txt"), mode='wb+') as of:
        of.write("Test passed.")
```

After a successful execution you should see the file `test.txt` with a content `"Test passed."` in your bucket.

Comment: Using the FileIO method that you described, I extended the `keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint` callback to save checkpoints in GCS. Based on Tensorflow 2.3. https://gist.github.com/seahrh/19c8779e159da35bcdc696245a2b24f6

Comment: Could we instead extend save_model to write directly on GCS to avoid writing checkpoint locally then saving/uploading to GCS?

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar problem and the solution above didn't work for me. The file must be read and be written in binary form. Otherwise this error will be thrown.

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte

So the code will be

```
def copy_file_to_gcs(job_dir, file_path):
    with file_io.FileIO(file_path, mode='rb') as input_f:
        with file_io.FileIO(os.path.join(job_dir, file_path), mode='wb+') as output_f:
            output_f.write(input_f.read())
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is my code that I wrote to save the model after each epoch.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import warnings
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

class ModelCheckpointGC(ModelCheckpoint):
"""Taken from and modified:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/tf-keras/keras/callbacks.py
"""

def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    logs = logs or {}
    self.epochs_since_last_save += 1
    if self.epochs_since_last_save >= self.period:
        self.epochs_since_last_save = 0
        filepath = self.filepath.format(epoch=epoch, **logs)
        if self.save_best_only:
            current = logs.get(self.monitor)
            if current is None:
                warnings.warn('Can save best model only with %s available, '
                              'skipping.' % (self.monitor), RuntimeWarning)
            else:
                if self.monitor_op(current, self.best):
                    if self.verbose > 0:
                        print('Epoch %05d: %s improved from %0.5f to %0.5f,'
                              ' saving model to %s'
                              % (epoch, self.monitor, self.best,
                                 current, filepath))
                    self.best = current
                    if self.save_weights_only:
                        self.model.save_weights(filepath, overwrite=True)
                    else:
                        if is_development():
                            self.model.save(filepath, overwrite=True)
                        else:
                            self.model.save(filepath.split(
                                "/")[-1])
                            with file_io.FileIO(filepath.split(
                                    "/")[-1], mode='rb') as input_f:
                                with file_io.FileIO(filepath, mode='wb+') as output_f:
                                    output_f.write(input_f.read())
                else:
                    if self.verbose > 0:
                        print('Epoch %05d: %s did not improve' %
                              (epoch, self.monitor))
        else:
            if self.verbose > 0:
                print('Epoch %05d: saving model to %s' % (epoch, filepath))
            if self.save_weights_only:
                self.model.save_weights(filepath, overwrite=True)
            else:
                if is_development():
                    self.model.save(filepath, overwrite=True)
                else:
                    self.model.save(filepath.split(
                        "/")[-1])
                    with file_io.FileIO(filepath.split(
                            "/")[-1], mode='rb') as input_f:
                        with file_io.FileIO(filepath, mode='wb+') as output_f:
                            output_f.write(input_f.read())
```

There is a function `is_development()` that checks if it is the local or gcloud environment. On the local environment I did set the variable `LOCAL_ENV=1`:

```
def is_development():
    """check if the environment is local or in the gcloud
    created the local variable in bash profile
    export LOCAL_ENV=1

    Returns:
        [boolean] -- True if local env
    """
    try:
        if os.environ['LOCAL_ENV'] == '1':
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except:
        return False
```

Then you can use it:

```
 ModelCheckpointGC(
            'gs://your_bucket/models/model.h5',
            monitor='loss',
            verbose=1,
            save_best_only=True,
            mode='min'))
```

I hope that helps someone and saves some time.

Answer (score 3):

A hacky workaround is to save to local filesystem, then copy using TF IO API. I added an example to the Keras example on GoogleCloudPlatform ML samples.

Basically it checks whether the target directory is a GCS path ("gs://") and will force writing h5py to the local filesystem, then copy to GCS using the TF file_io API. See for example: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/census/keras/trainer/task.py#L146

Comment: Thanks Jochen, the code in the Pull Request to GoogleCloudPlatform indeed solved the issue. If you edited your answer to include a description of how the hack works along with a complete working code example I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Jochen, should `mode='w+'` be `mode='wb+'` in line 138 as @Manash pointed out?

Answer (score 2):

For me the easiest way is to use gsutil.

```
model.save('model.h5')
!gsutil -m cp model.h5 gs://name-of-cloud-storage/model.h5
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why this is not mentioned already, but there is a solution where you don't need to add a copy function in your code.

Install [gcsfuse](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse) following these steps:

```
export GCSFUSE_REPO=gcsfuse-`lsb_release -c -s`
echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $GCSFUSE_REPO main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gcsfuse.list
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcsfuse
```

Then mount your bucket locally:

```
mkdir bucket
gcsfuse <cloud_bucket_name> bucket
```

and then use the local directory `bucket/` as the logdir of your model.

Syncing of cloud and local directory will be automated for you and your code can stay clean.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
tf.keras.models.save_model(model, filepath, save_format="tf")
```

*save_format*: Either 'tf' or 'h5', indicating whether to save the model to Tensorflow SavedModel or HDF5. Defaults to 'tf' in TF 2.X, and 'h5' in TF 1.X.