# No such file or directory Error with Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I quite new to Google Cloud Platform and I am trying to train a model with TPU. I follow this [tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/nlp-tutorial-creating-question-answering-system-using-bert-squad-on-colab-tpu-1utp3352) to set up the TPU with Google Colab. All the code below follows the tutorial.

This is the step I have done:

```
import datetime
import json
import os
import pprint
import random
import string
import sys
import tensorflow as tf

assert 'COLAB_TPU_ADDR' in os.environ, 'ERROR: Not connected to a TPU runtime; please see the first cell in this notebook for instructions!'
TPU_ADDRESS = 'grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR']
print('TPU address is => ', TPU_ADDRESS)

from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
with tf.Session(TPU_ADDRESS) as session:
  print('TPU devices:')
  pprint.pprint(session.list_devices())

  # Upload credentials to TPU.
  with open('/content/adc.json', 'r') as f:
    auth_info = json.load(f)
  tf.contrib.cloud.configure_gcs(session, credentials=auth_info)
  # Now credentials are set for all future sessions on this TPU.
```

Output:

```
TPU address is =>  grpc://10.4.89.154:8470
```

Provide my `BUCKET` name and `OUPUT DIRECTORY` name:

```
BUCKET = 'my_xlnet' #@param {type:"string"}
assert BUCKET, '*** Must specify an existing GCS bucket name ***'
output_dir_name = 'xlnet_output' #@param {type:"string"}
BUCKET_NAME = 'gs://{}'.format(BUCKET)
OUTPUT_DIR = 'gs://{}/{}'.format(BUCKET,output_dir_name)
tf.gfile.MakeDirs(OUTPUT_DIR)
print('***** Model output directory: {} *****'.format(OUTPUT_DIR))
```

Move the pretrained model to GCS bucket:

```
!gsutil mv /content/xlnet_extension_tf/model/xlnet_cased_L-24_H-1024_A-16 $BUCKET_NAME
```

Output:

```
...
Operation completed over 5 objects/1.3 GiB.
```

Then run the main code:

```
!python /content/xlnet_extension_tf/run_coqa.py \
--use_tpu=True \
--tpu_name=grpc://10.4.89.154:8470 \
--spiece_model_file=$BUCKET_NAME/xlnet_cased_L-24_H-1024_A-16/spiece.model \
--model_config_path=$BUCKET_NAME/xlnet_cased_L-24_H-1024_A-16/xlnet_config.json \
--init_checkpoint=$BUCKET_NAME/xlnet_cased_L-24_H-1024_A-16/xlnet_model.ckpt \
...
```

Then I got this error:

```
OSError: Not found: "gs://my_xlnet/xlnet_cased_L-24_H-1024_A-16/spiece.model": No such file or directory Error #2
```

This is the GCS bucket screen:
[image]

I don't know why this error exists because I can move my pretrained model to the bucket successfully.

Do you guys know how to fix this?

**Update:**

The `run_coqa.py` file: https://github.com/stevezheng23/xlnet_extension_tf/blob/master/run_coqa.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post the part where `run_coqa.py` is opening the file?

It seems like you're trying to open it with a regular `os.` command where you should be using GCP's sdk.

Comment: I have just updated my post with the link of the `run_coqa.py` file.

Comment: I'm a bit out of my depth here, but this seems relevant. It seems that you need a specific implementation to be able to open `gs://` files. Check response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45585104/save-keras-modelcheckpoints-in-google-cloud-bucket)

Comment: huy: Did aldarisbm's suggestion help you?

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial was created by a third party. I cannot see any common issue going on right now that would stop this code from running.